# How to extract some text from a column to create a new column

Tags: perl, selection, text-extraction

Dear stackoverflow community,

I have a 2 columns file that looks like this:

```
Ccrux.00013.c0_g1_i1    .
Ccrux.00013.c0_g2_i1    .
Ccrux.00014.c0_g1_i1    .
Ccrux.00014.c0_g2_i1    .
Ccrux.00015.c0_g1_i1    .
Ccrux.00015.c0_g1_i1    GO:0005789^cellular_component^endoplasmic reticulum membrane`GO:0016021^cellular_component^integral component of membrane`GO:0005509^molecular_function^calcium ion binding`GO:0005506^molecular_function^iron ion binding`GO:0031418^molecular_function^L-ascorbic acid binding`GO:0016706^molecular_function^oxidoreductase activity, acting on paired donors, with incorporation or reduction of molecular oxygen, 2-oxoglutarate as one donor, and incorporation of one atom each of oxygen into both donors`GO:0045646^biological_process^regulation of erythrocyte differentiation
Ccrux.00015.c0_g2_i1    GO:0005789^cellular_component^endoplasmic reticulum membrane`GO:0016021^cellular_component^integral component of membrane`GO:0005509^molecular_function^calcium ion binding`GO:0005506^molecular_function^iron ion binding`GO:0031418^molecular_function^L-ascorbic acid binding`GO:0016706^molecular_function^oxidoreductase activity, acting on paired donors, with incorporation or reduction of molecular oxygen, 2-oxoglutarate as one donor, and incorporation of one atom each of oxygen into both donors`GO:0045646^biological_process^regulation of erythrocyte differentiation
Ccrux.00016.c0_g1_i1    .
Ccrux.00016.c0_g2_i1    .
Ccrux.00017.c0_g1_i1    .
Ccrux.00018.c0_g1_i1    .
Ccrux.00019.c0_g1_i1    .
```

I need a new 2 columns file that:

- Doesn't contain the rows where the 2nd column value is .
- Only contains GO:XXXXXXX as 2nd column value (i.e. eliminates from the 2nd column all the text and only retains the GO numbers)

The new file should look like:

```
Ccrux.00015.c0_g1_i1    GO:0005789,GO:0016021,GO:0005509,GO:0005506,GO:0031418,GO:0016706,GO:0045646
Ccrux.00015.c0_g2_i1    GO:0005789,GO:0016021,GO:0005509,GO:0005506,GO:0031418,GO:0016706,GO:0045646
Ccrux.00029.c0_g1_i1    GO:0035869,GO:0005737,GO:0005615,GO:0016020,GO:0021956,GO:0060271,GO:0021904,GO:0001701,GO:0001841,GO:0008589,GO:0021523,GO:0021537
```

I've been trying with perl:

```
perl -ne '/(GO:\d+)/ && print "$1"' input.file > output.file
```

But prints me all the GO numbers in just one column. I'm really lost about how to do it. Any suggestions will be more than welcome.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've got there pattern matches a piece of text, and just prints that.

From what it *sounds* like you're doing:

```
GO:0005789^cellular_component^endoplasmic reticulum membrane`
```

You're trying to remove any 'bits' between `^` and the next `GO`?

The nice thing with `perl` is that that syntax `-ne` just creates a little `while` loop around the commands - so it will let you do multiple statements.

So - expanded example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    next unless m/GO/;
    s/\^[^`]+`/,/g;
    s/\^[^`]+$/\n/g;
    print;
}

__DATA__
Ccrux.00013.c0_g1_i1    .
Ccrux.00013.c0_g2_i1    .
Ccrux.00014.c0_g1_i1    .
Ccrux.00014.c0_g2_i1    .
Ccrux.00015.c0_g1_i1    .
Ccrux.00015.c0_g1_i1    GO:0005789^cellular_component^endoplasmic reticulum membrane`GO:0016021^cellular_component^integral component of membrane`GO:0005509^molecular_function^calcium ion binding`GO:0005506^molecular_function^iron ion binding`GO:0031418^molecular_function^L-ascorbic acid binding`GO:0016706^molecular_function^oxidoreductase activity, acting on paired donors, with incorporation or reduction of molecular oxygen, 2-oxoglutarate as one donor, and incorporation of one atom each of oxygen into both donors`GO:0045646^biological_process^regulation of erythrocyte differentiation
Ccrux.00015.c0_g2_i1    GO:0005789^cellular_component^endoplasmic reticulum membrane`GO:0016021^cellular_component^integral component of membrane`GO:0005509^molecular_function^calcium ion binding`GO:0005506^molecular_function^iron ion binding`GO:0031418^molecular_function^L-ascorbic acid binding`GO:0016706^molecular_function^oxidoreductase activity, acting on paired donors, with incorporation or reduction of molecular oxygen, 2-oxoglutarate as one donor, and incorporation of one atom each of oxygen into both donors`GO:0045646^biological_process^regulation of erythrocyte differentiation
Ccrux.00016.c0_g1_i1    .
Ccrux.00016.c0_g2_i1    .
Ccrux.00017.c0_g1_i1    .
Ccrux.00018.c0_g1_i1    .
Ccrux.00019.c0_g1_i1    .
```

This will generate as output:

```
Ccrux.00015.c0_g1_i1    GO:0005789,GO:0016021,GO:0005509,GO:0005506,GO:0031418,GO:0016706,GO:0045646
Ccrux.00015.c0_g2_i1    GO:0005789,GO:0016021,GO:0005509,GO:0005506,GO:0031418,GO:0016706,GO:0045646
```

We:

- skip any line without the word `GO` in it.
- replace any instance of literal `^`, one or more not `^` and then backtick - with a comma.
- and replace the same terminated at end of line with `\n`.

This we can condense to a one liner thus:

```
perl -ne 'next unless m/GO/;s/\^[^`]+`/,/g;s/\^[^`]+$/\n/g;print' inputfile > outputfile
```

Or perhaps better - without the print - see [`perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) - `-p` is similar to `-n` but it builds in the `print` (so works a bit more like `sed`).

```
perl -pe 'next unless m/GO/;s/\^[^`]+`/,/g;s/\^[^`]+$/\n/g;' inputfile > outputfile
```

Comment: Almost @Sobrique! Both of them gave me back this:
 `Ccrux.00015.c0_g1_i1    GO:0005789,GO:0016021,GO:0005509,GO:0005506,GO:0031418,GO:0016706,GO:0045646^biological_process^regulation of erythrocyte differentiation
Ccrux.00015.c0_g2_i1    GO:0005789,GO:0016021,GO:0005509,GO:0005506,GO:0031418,GO:0016706,GO:0045646^biological_process^regulation of erythrocyte differentiation`

Comment: Yeah, end of line doesn't have a backtick. Updated. Give that a try.

Comment: Now is working, @Sobrique. Thanks! Any idea about how to remove the rows which 2nd column value is .?

Comment: `next unless m/GO/; `

Answer (score 0):

I think your requirement is a little too long for a one-line solution, but it can be very brief. This program will produce the output that you describe. It expects the path to the input file as a parameter on the command line

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <> ) {
    next unless my @values = /GO:\d+/g;
    local $" = ',';
    s/\S\s+\K.+/@values/;
    print;
}
```

A one-line version would be a little clunky

```
perl -pe '@v=/GO:\d+/g or next; $"=","; s/\S\s+\K.+/@v/; print;' myfile > newfile
```